# What is the significance of the initial rep of 1 on any stack exchange site?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

I am new to SO. I was wondering why the initial rep is 1 (and not 0) on any new stack exchange site that I join?

Comment: Because 1 is psychologically more than 0. Here at Stack Exchange, everyone is at least a one, not a zero.

Comment: one rep for simply signjng up snd joining the community? :P

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's also mathematically more than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're a member, you have basic privileges (such as asking and answering questions), as such you have positive reputation.

Zero would suggest the system has zero confidence in you and that's not true; it has limited confidence in you.

Not strictly related but you only start at 1 on new sites while you don't have at least 200 rep on one site; once you get 200 you'll get an association bonus of 100 on every site you're a member of.

Comment: When a user is suspended their reputation is temporarily set to one; if what you are asserting were correct I would expect it to be set to zero instead.  Of course setting it to zero would make more sense, IMHO, but I'm not sure the "system" sees this the way you're thinking about it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would agree, suspention should mean zero. That said; it really doesn't matter